# How can I access smartphone's gps service is enabled or disabled with javascript?

Tags: javascript, gps

I am trying to get location of visitors. I am using google map api. In computer it works fine. But in mobile, if gps service is disabled, browser doesn't ask for permission or dipslay result. When gps service is enabled, browser asks for permission or display result. So, is there a way to access gps service is enabled or disabled via javascript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you support HTML5, you might find HTML5 Geolocation useful.

[This](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) page contains the following example code:

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
</script>
```